# Custom Emmet Snippets in VsCode not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Snippets.json file

```
{
    "html": {
        "snippets": {
            "will": "{Apple}"
        }
    }
}
```

Settings.json file in vs code

```
"emmet.extensionsPath": "~/.emmet/"
```

`code ~/.emmet/snippets.json`

was the command used to create the snippets.json file

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Reloaded vscode, doesn't work. Maybe something wrong with the extension path?

Comment: you need to specify the full path in format `/c:/dir1/dir2` if you are on Windows, for Linux just full path

Comment: @rioV8 I am on mac. /Users/basic101/.emmet/settings.json or /Users/basic101/.emmet tried both of these but didn't work.

Comment: I only have VSC on Windows and that path worked for me, what if you use a path without a `.` (period). It has to be a directory, so first try should fail

Comment: @rioV8 .emmet is a directory. Its just named .emmet, do you think this might be the reason its not working? Anyways its ok, just starting to learn emmet. Even if it doesnt work, I will maybe use vs code custom snippets. Thanx for helping. Cheers

Comment: if you can't find a path that works file an issue for the emmet extension and ask to update the docs with examples for paths for the different OS